# Plotting list of points while ignoring missing or infinite values

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, ps

My question is closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156755/70966), which has not been answered yet and might get more attention in this more general formulation.

Suppose that a bunch of (abscissa, ordinate) points contains missing or infinite values which can be flagged somehow, for instance by directly having `nan` in the ordinate as I assume below, or by testing out-of-bounds values as in the [above mentioned question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156755/70966). Is there a simple modification of `\listplot` which would plot a *different curve for each group of contiguous values without missing/infinite value* ?

Below is an illustration. First, I plot in black lines the data with no missing values. Then, I give the same points but with missing values; I use a trick redefining `nan` (or any user-defined flag) to simply get rid of them. However, the plot in red is not satisfying, because lines are connecting surrounding values. In blue, I plot "by hand" (i.e. by calling on several `\listplot`) the result I would like to get automatically; note that an isolated point can simply be discarded.

```
\begin{pspicture}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=7pt](0,0)(10,4)

\savedata{\data}[1 2  2 1  3 1  4 2    5 1    6 2  7 3  8 1    9 2  10 3]
\listplot[linecolor=black]{\data}

\savedata{\data}[1 2  2 1  3 1  4 nan  5 nan  6 2  7 3  8 nan  9 2  10 nan]
\pstVerb{/nan { pop } def} % nice trick to get rid of nan values
\pstScalePoints(1.,1.){}{.1 add} % some vertical shift to allow comparison
\listplot[linecolor=red]{\data}

\pstScalePoints(1.,1.){}{.2 add} % some vertical shift to allow comparison
\savedata{\data}[1 2  2 1  3 1]
\listplot[linecolor=blue]{\data}
\savedata{\data}[6 2  7 3]
\listplot[linecolor=blue]{\data}
% the following goes wrong because isolated point is completed with (0,0)
% \savedata{\data}[9 2]
% \listplot[linecolor=blue]{\data} 
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `pstricks` a requirement, or would a `pgfplots` method be of interest?

Comment: this is supposed to be used within a long pstricks macro (and this is why I do not want to resort to splitting in several `\listplot` commands), so I'd rather have a version that works with `pstricks`.

Comment: I see, then I won't waste your time with that.

Comment: thanks anyway! (and if I do not find a reasonable `pstricks` way of doing it, I might consider shifting to other graphical packages around)

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I got no luck so far, and I am pretty sure such functionality would be useful to others than me. If you ever get the time to detail a `pgfplot` alternative, I would take it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfplots` has this feature built in, with the option `unbounded coords=jump`.

I don't know where your data comes from. If you have them in a text file `data.dat` with the format

```
1 2 
2 1
3 1
4 nan
etc.
```

then you can use that directly in the `\addplot` command, as `\addplot [unbounded coords=jump] table {data.dat};`. If you have multiple columns in a file, you can select which ones to use with e.g. `\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {data.dat};`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{ % read in data
1 2 
2 1
3 1
4 nan
5 nan
6 2
7 3
8 nan
9 2
10 nan
}\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
% axis limits
xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=4,
% size of plot
% scale only axis means that 10cm is only the axis, not the ticks
width=10cm,height=4cm,scale only axis, 
% add grid
grid=major
]
% plot data with gaps in line
\addplot [blue,very thick,unbounded coords=jump] table {\data};
% default setting, no gaps
\addplot [red,dashed] table {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Built-in... I really like `pstricks` but this goes definitely in favor of  `pgf` + `tickz`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,4)
\savedata{\data}[1 2  2 1  3 1  4 2  5 1 6 2  7 3  8 1 9 2  10 3]
\listplot{\data}
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,nStart=1,nEnd=3]{\data}
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,nStart=6,nEnd=7]{\data}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have emphasized the *automatic* part of the feature I am looking for; at least, without having to split *manually* into several `\listplot` commands. I am thinking right away of a command preprocessing the data and generating suitable `\listplot` with appropriate `nStart` and `nEnd`, but my knowledge of both latex and postscript is too poor to make such a command from scratch